# Дни недели в C#

Tags: c#

Как зная сегодняшнюю дату, узнать даты всех дней этой недели в c#? Также требуется получить даты всех дней месяца.

Comment: [Calendar.GetDayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.calendar.getdayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Calendar.GetDayOfMonth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.calendar.getdayofmonth(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Почитайте статью про DateTime https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/19.1.php

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
//Высчитываем начало недели
var weekStart = today.AddDays(-(int)today.DayOfWeek + 1);
//Высчитываем начало месяца
var monthStart = today.AddDays(-today.Day + 1);
var week = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(count => weekStart.AddDays(count)).ToList();
var month = Enumerable.Range(0, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month))
            .Select(count => monthStart.AddDays(count)).ToList();
```

В случае использования разных культур замените расчет начала недели на такой

```
var cultureStart = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
var weekStart = today;
while (weekStart.DayOfWeek != cultureStart) weekStart = weekStart.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Хм, а если неделя начинается с понедельника/воскресенья/субботы?

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно

Comment: @АндрейNOP обновил